# List of key values from JSONArray (java/android)

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON that is made of JSONArray's. How do I get a list of the key strings from the JSONArrays?

For example:

```
{
  "mainKey": [
    {
      "keyValue1": [
        {
          "id": 9000, 
          "name": "John Doe"
        }
      ]
    }, 
    {
      "keyValue2": []
    }, 
    {
      "keyValue3": []
    }, 
    {
      "keyValue4": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to obtain an ArrayList with keyValue1, keyValue2 and so on. How should I do this in Java?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Try the org.json library: http://www.json.org/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("mainKey");
for(int n = 0; n < array.length(); n++)
{
    JSONObject keyObject = array.getJSONObject(n);
    Iterator<?> keys = keyObject.keys();
    while( keys.hasNext() ) {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        if ( obj.get(key) instanceof JSONArray ) {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but with arrayList.add(key) instead of the println and i'm getting an empty list.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this in an Android AsyncTask:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
Spinner spinner;
```

...

```
       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_class, container, false);

spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewByID(R.id.spinner);

LoadFromAPI task = new LoadFromAPI();
task.execute(url);   // a valid url in a localhost


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(rootView.getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
return rootView;
}
    private class LoadFromAPI extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    protected void doInBackground (String... url) {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
        JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("mainKey");
        for(int n = 0; n < array.length(); n++)
        {
            JSONObject keyObject = array.getJSONObject(n);
            Iterator<?> keys = keyObject.keys();
            while( keys.hasNext() ) {
                String key = (String)keys.next();
                if ( obj.get(key) instanceof JSONArray ) {
                    arrayList.add(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class JSONFun {

    public static List<String> firstKeysOf(JSONArray array) {
        return IntStream.range(0, array.length())
                .mapToObj(i -> array.getJSONObject(i).keys().next())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note, this isn't safe. It will fail violently if the array contains anything other than a JSONObject with at least one key.

Comment: I'm using Java 8 but I can't import java.util.stream libraries!